# AutoFilter method of Range class failed in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to use some Parsing i was able to tweak a little.  If I use it in straight VBA in excel, it works fine.  However, when I use the same code as a module in VB.NET I get the error in the title on the line of code

> ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter()

(duh!)  I am not sure what is going wrong in the conversion, since I am not a hardcore VB.Net programmer, so I am doing a lot of googling, but not finding much that works.  Any ideas on how this could be fixed or do I have to abandon the idea of using this snippet in VB.Net?

Here is the code I am using:

```
'turned strict off or autofilter per     http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/autofilter-method-of-range-class-failed.3994483/
Option Strict Off
Imports xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module ParseItems

Public Sub ParseItems(ByRef fileName As String)
    'Jerry Beaucaire  (4/22/2010)
    'Based on selected column, data is filtered to individual workbooks are named for the value plus today's date
    Dim wb As xl.Workbook
    Dim xlApp As xl.Application
    Dim LR As Long, Itm As Long, MyCount As Long, vCol As Long
    Dim ws As xl.Worksheet, MyArr As Object, vTitles As String, SvPath As String

    'Set new application and make wb visible
    xlApp = New xl.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True

    'open workbook
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)


    'Sheet with data in it
    ws = wb.Sheets("Original Data")

    'Path to save files into, remember the final "\"
    SvPath = "G:\MC VBA test\"

    'Range where titles are across top of data, as string, data MUST have titles in this row, edit to suit your titles locale
    vTitles = "A1:L1"

    'Choose column to evaluate from, column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
    vCol = xlApp.InputBox("What column to split data by? " & vbLf & vbLf & "(A=1, B=2, C=3, etc)", "Which column?", 1, Type:=1)
    If vCol = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Spot bottom row of data
    LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vCol).End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

    'Speed up macro execution
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Get a temporary list of unique values from key column
    ws.Columns(vCol).AdvancedFilter(Action:=xl.XlFilterAction.xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws.Range("EE1"), Unique:=True)

    'Sort the temporary list
    ws.Columns("EE:EE").Sort(Key1:=ws.Range("EE2"), Order1:=xl.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Header:=xl.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, _
       OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xl.Constants.xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xl.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)

    'Put list into an array for looping (values cannot be the result of formulas, must be constants)
    MyArr = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("EE2:EE" & ws.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xl.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants))

    'clear temporary worksheet list
    ws.Range("EE:EE").Clear()

    'Turn on the autofilter, one column only is all that is needed
    ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter()

    'Loop through list one value at a time
    For Itm = 1 To UBound(MyArr)
        ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter(Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=MyArr(Itm))

        ws.Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy()
        xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xl.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll)
        ws.Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
        MyCount = MyCount + ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp).Row - 1

        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(SvPath & MyArr(Itm), xl.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal)
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SvPath & MyArr(Itm) & Format(Date, " MM-DD-YY") & ".xlsx", 51   'use for Excel 2007+
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False)

        ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter(Field:=vCol)
    Next Itm

    'Cleanup
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    MsgBox("Rows with data: " & (LR - 1) & vbLf & "Rows copied to other sheets: " & MyCount & vbLf & "Hope they match!!")
    xlApp.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



End Module
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `vTitles` with just the range? Also can you try this `ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter(Nothing, Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues)`

Comment: @Zaggler Yes I have, it landed the same error.  I also tried your snippet in its place, and received the same error as well.

Comment: Looks like something like `ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter(Field:=1)` works.

Comment: @JimHewitt that did the trick...I feel a bit dumb now,  Thank you!  Submit that as an answer and I'll close this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify at least one optional parameter.  Try this:

`ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter(Field:=1)`

Answer (score -1):

I realize this was closed years ago, but I recently ran into this problem and wanted to add to the solution.

This seems to only work when specifically using the first optional `Field` parameter. I attempted this fix using the optional `VisibleDropDown` parameter and still got this error.

`ws.Range["A1"].AutoFilter(VisibleDropDown: true);`  **Gives error**

`ws.Range["A1"].AutoFilter(Field: 1);`  **No error**